# Existence of non-analytic, $\mathscr{C}^\infty$ continuations

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

The identity theorem in complex analysis states that a holomorphic function $f\colon U \subseteq \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined on a domain $U$ is identically zero if there exists a subset $S \subseteq U$ with accumulation in $U$ such that $f$ vanishes on $S$. The identity theorem can be used to show that the $\Gamma$ function is the only analytic function such that
$$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
This can be generalised to several dimensions into what is known as the curve selection lemma (see e.g. Milnor's [Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1bd6kvv)).
However, this is possible due to the *rigid* nature of holomorphic derivatives.

I have recently been wondering about the concept of a "$\mathscr{C}^\infty$ continuation". For example, could we find a non-analytic, $\mathscr{C}^\infty$ function $G\colon I \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on an open neighbourhood of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $G(n)=(n-1)!$? This implies that one cannot find a bi-analytic function $\phi\colon I \to J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Gamma\circ \phi=G$, so $G$ is not *equivalent* to $\Gamma$ either (as [the so-called $\Pi$ function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4Trz6pFut4) would be).

I presume someone has come up with this topic at one point (although my *MathSciNet-fu* is not as strong as I would like it to be, so I am not sure how to go about it), and there may be some condition under which every $\mathscr{C}^\infty$ *continuation* (using the term loosely) needs to be analytic. Otherwise, is there an example of a function which admits two different non-analytic continuations?

Comment: The Gamma function is not unique analytic function s.t $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$. One can construct entire functions which vanishes exactly at the integers $z = n$(by Weierstrass factorization theorem) and one can simply add this to make another such function. The problem is that natural numbers does not have accumulation point.

Comment: note that even if you add the functional equation $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ in the mix and the continuation is not unique since if you take any period $1$ entire function $h, h(0)=1$ , we have $F(z)=h(z)\Gamma(z)$ satisfying same relations; you need a growth condition on $\Gamma$ or other stuff for unicity (there is logarithmic convexity condition on reals that ensures unicity too); note that if we take a continuous (but not analytic) periodic function $h$ we get as many non analytic $\Gamma$ like functions as we want

Comment: Apologies for the belated reply. Thank you everyone for your insightful comments, and for not bashing my ignorance! My area of expertise leans closer to complex than real analysis, so I guess I got completely lured by the "niceness" of holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smooth functions are extremely flexible. Essentially, any shape you can think of (with bounded slope, etc…) can be achieved as a graph of a smooth function. An example of why this is true is given by the tool called [partition of unity](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partition+of+unity): this allows to “glue” the graph of two different smooth functions, e.g., given two domains $A$, $B$ with positive distance between each other, which are both compactly embedded into a third domain $D$, and given two smooth functions $f$ and $g$ defined on a neighbourhood of $A, B$ respectively, there always exists a smooth function $h$ that is defined on all $C$ and coincides with $f$ on $A$ and with $g$ on $B$.

Another tool is that of [mollification/regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Smoothing_property). For any rough function $f$ (e.g., locally integrable, or even a distribution), you can construct a family of smooth functions $f_\varepsilon$ (parametrized by some parameter $\varepsilon>0$) that locally resemble the original function, with a series of nice properties (e.g., if $f$ is continuous on an open subset, you have local uniform convergence of $f_\varepsilon$ to $f$ on that set,…). The regularization $f_\varepsilon$ is constructed by taking the convolution between $f$ and a fixed smooth, non-negative function $\rho_\varepsilon$ with integral $1$ that is supported on a ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around the origin (this tool is available on $\mathbb R^n$ for all $n$).

With this tool you can easily construct what you want: consider the following function defined on $\mathbb C$:
$$ f(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} (n-1)! \cdot \mathbf 1_{B_{1/2}(n)}(z), $$
where the above are indicator functions of the balls of radius $1/2$ centered around the natural numbers. Then, regularizing $f$, we obtain a smooth function $f_\varepsilon$ which locally resembles $f$ for small $\varepsilon$: in particular, if $\varepsilon$ is small enough, $f_\varepsilon$ councides with $f$ in a neighbourhood of $\mathbb N$ (I can try to give you some references if you want to know more about this method).

**Edit:** I agree with the comments you received about the non-uniqueness of $\Gamma$, but what I discussed here is unrelated from that and applies to a large variety of settings. For instance take
$$ g(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} \mathbf 1_{B_{1/2}(n)}(z).$$
As before, $g_\epsilon$ is smooth, and equals $1$ on a neighbourhood of $\mathbb N$. Then, $h(z):=g_\varepsilon(z)\Gamma(z)$ is smooth and agrees with $\Gamma$ on a neighbourhood of $\mathbb  N$, but it vanishes for all $z$ that lie on a slightly larger neighbourhood of $\mathbb N$.